# Simple php framework to support multi-tenancy

Tags: multi-tenant

I am looking for a PHP based framework which is ready to go  with following features
1. Simple dashboard with login/logout
2. Multiple DB with each db representing a client
Just the basic framework.
3. Simple registration support

Use case:
I download from github and deploy on the server - Assume the server is all configured up with dns and stuff.

I create a user through registration - a new db is created and tenant folder created on the server

I can then access

tenant1.stckoveawesm.com

tenant2.stckoveawesm.com

each connecting to different db. Assume: *.stckoveawesm.com is mapped to the server I am hosting the framework on.

I know there is code igniter, Zend and Symphony that supports the framework. I m looking for a library/framework which is ready to go. A shell code which can just do the trick with min. config.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally managed to get something done using Laravel framework and is hosted on github for folks to help and improve. Any one wants to pitch in and help fork and let me know so I can collaborate.
https://github.com/sseshachala/laravel-multi-tenant